# How to log GC output to specific file including the PID in the filename?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

The Hotspot JVM allows to log GC output to a specific file using the -Xloggc: option.

The problem is that I have several JVM instances running all of them reading the same configuration options from a common XML configuration file so I can only see the output of one of the instances.

To avoid this behavior I would like each of them to log to a different file that includes the PID in the filename. Something like:

```
-Xloggc:/var/log/jvm_gc_<PID>.log
```

where < PID > would be the PID of the JVM instances.

I don't know if the HotSpot is able to interpolate this like for example the linux bash shell with $$.

Answer (score 10):

You may use `%p` but it works only since Java 8:

```
-Xloggc:/var/log/jvm_gc_%p.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the apangin's answer:
`%t in file name will be replaced by time string: YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS`

Source: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7164841